# The Border after every menu items are extending the topbar not displaying properly and also newsbar not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, web

The border after every menu item ie after news,sports,whether etc are extending the top bar the height should be similiar to the top bar should not go out of the top bar

And also the the bar below the top bar which is news bar is not displaying properly check the image link which is the required output for ref see the images click on ***This is correct image***  link below

To see the code click the link below "***Click Me to see the code***"

[This is correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TSd4.png)

[Click Me to see the code](http://jsbin.com/jubowonoga/1/edit?html,output)

```
**HTML**
    <html>
    <head>
   <title> BBC NEWS</title>
   </head>
   <body>
<div class="container">
<div class="topbar">
<div class="fixwidth">
<div class="bbclogo">
<img src="../Images/bbc logo.PNG"/>
</div>    
<div class="signin">
<img src="../Images/Signin.PNG"/>Sign In
</div>  
<div class="topmenu">
<ul>
<li>News</li>
<li>Sports</li>
<li>Weather</li>
<li>IPlayer</li>
<li>TV</li>
<li>Radio</li>
<li>More...</li>
</ul>                                                                                  
</div> 
<div class="search">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
</div>
<div class="empty"></div>
<div class="newsbar">
<div class="fixwidth">
</div>      
</div>       
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
margin:0;
}
.topbar{
background-color:#7A0000;
height:40px;
width:100%;
color:white;
font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
position:fixed;
}
.fixwidth{
margin:0 auto;
width:1150px;
}
.bbclogo{
padding:5px;
float:left;
border-right:1px solid #990000;
padding-right:10px;
}
.signin{
padding:8px 80px 12px 20px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
float:left;
border-right:1px solid #990000;
margin-top:3px;
}
.signin img{
position:relative;
top:1px;
}
.topmenu{
float:left;
}
.topmenu ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.topmenu li{
float:left;
list-style:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
border-right:1px solid #990000;
height:100%;
padding:10px 20px 0 20px;
line-height:1;
}
.search{
float:left;
padding:8px;
}
.search input{
height:25px;
border:none;
padding:3px;
font-size:12px;
font-family:Times New Roman;
font-style:italic;
background-image:url(../../../blq-search_grey_alpha.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:right center;
}
.empty{
clear:both;
}
.newsbar{
background-color:#990000;
height:40px;
width:100%;
color:white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You should post also some code here or at least the relevant code because if the third external source brokes, this question has no sense anymore.

Comment: @Error404 code is too long

Comment: This is why I said _relevant code_. To be a good question you should debug a bit in your project and come here with the focus on the problem (not the solution, only know where the problem is).

Comment: @Error404 changes made above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for newsbar you have to change your height and width like below :

```
.newsbar{background-color:#990000; height:5000px; width:100%; color:white; }
```

Will definately works ☺

Comment: didnt work the height of news bars increases see the image link above for correct output

Answer (score 2):

Removed the height of navbar and made necessary changes

[Demo Link](http://jsbin.com/yulaziyodu/1/edit?html,output)

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> BBC NEWS</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
margin:0;
}
.topbar{
background-color:#7A0000;
/*height:40px;*/ /* removed*/ 
width:100%;
color:white;
font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
position:fixed;
}
.fixwidth{
margin:0 auto;
width:1050px;
}
.bbclogo{
padding:13px;
float:left;
border-right:1px solid #990000;
padding-right:10px;
}
.signin{
padding:8px 80px 12px 20px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
float:left;
border-right:1px solid #990000;
margin-top:3px;
}
.signin img{
position:relative;
top:1px;
}
.topmenu{
float:left;
}
.topmenu ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;

}
.topmenu li{
float:left;
list-style:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
border-right:1px solid #990000;
height:100%;
padding: 4px 20px 0 20px; /* changed */ 
line-height: 2.8; /* added */ 

}
.search{
float:left;
padding:8px;
}
.search input{
height:25px;
border:none;
padding:3px;
font-size:12px;
font-family:Times New Roman;
font-style:italic;
background-image:url(../../../blq-search_grey_alpha.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:right center;

}
.empty{
clear:both;
}

.newsbar{
background-color:#990000;
height:40px;
width:100%;
color:white;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="topbar">
<div class="fixwidth">
<div class="bbclogo">
<img src="../Images/bbc logo.PNG"/>
</div>    
<div class="signin">
<img src="../Images/Signin.PNG"/>Sign In
</div>  
<div class="topmenu">
<ul>
<li>News</li>
<li>Sports</li>
<li>Weather</li>
<li>IPlayer</li>
<li>TV</li>
<li>Radio</li>
<li>More...</li>
</ul>                                                                                  
</div> 
<div class="search">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
</div>

<div class="empty"></div>

<div class="newsbar">
<div class="fixwidth">

</div>      
</div>       
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check the link your one is wrong please also check the image properly [link(]http://web.archive.org/web/20140402131524/http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk)

Comment: @Mandar Sant If the fix is what you are looking for please mark it as answered.

Comment: Could you please explain what you are looking for exactly ?

Comment: check the image for correct output click on "This is correct image" the output in the image is the required one